# Create A Channel using Youtube API in .Net

Tags: youtube-api, gdata, channel

The new youtube api (2.1 and 3.0) supports creating a channel for youtube if the google account is not linked to youtube
http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/10/introducing-google-account-support-and.html

i am using C#, can any one hint me about how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no support for adding a YouTube channel to an unlinked Google Account in v3 of the API.

There is a [v2.1 API call](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_profiles#Upgrading_an_Unlinked_Google_Account), but unfortunately the existing [.NET GData client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/) doesn't have built-in support for that call, as you've noticed.

You can make the underlying `HTTP PUT` yourself using standard [.NET HTTPWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) calls.

Alternatively, you can ask your users to go through the web-based flow starting with https://www.youtube.com/create_channel (or https://m.youtube.com/create_channel on mobile devices).